# Numeric Operand Is Required?

Tags: string, macros, sas, eval, numeric

Does anyone know how i can correct the following?

CODE:

```
    %macro variables(list);
    data tire.Import2(drop=i count);
    set tire.Import;
    by Away_Team;

    %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&list));
    %DO k=1 %TO &n;
    %let val = %scan (&list,&k);

    array x(*) &val.lag1-&val.lag6;
    &val.lag1=lag1(&val);
    &val.lag2=lag2(&val)+lag1(&val);
    &val.lag3=lag3(&val)+lag2(&val)+lag1(&val);
    &val.lag4=lag4(&val)+lag3(&val)+lag2(&val)+lag1(&val);
    &val.lag5=lag5(&val)+lag4(&val)+lag3(&val)+lag2(&val)+lag1(&val);
    &val.lag6=lag6(&val)+lag5(&val)+lag4(&val)+lag3(&val)+lag2(&val)+lag1(&val);

    %if %str(first.Away_Team) %then count=1;

    %do i=count %to dim(x);
    x(i)=.;
    %end;
    count + 1;

    run;
    %end;
    %mend;
    %variables(FTHG FTHGC);
```

> ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF
>   condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:
>   %str(first.Away_Team) ERROR: The macro VARIABLES will stop executing.

I tried using `%bquote` and `%str` but no luck!

Comment: I don't know the SAS language, but a quick Google says %str is a _quoting function_. This sounds like it's putting quotes around the argument, and then it's no longer a numerical value fit for using with %if.

Comment: Your macro %do loop at the end should probably be a data step do loop.

Comment: Also your %if %str(first). Should be if first.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments. Someone else will write better explanation of %do vs do and %if vs if, or I will add one this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro is confusing macro %IF statements vs data step IF statements, and %DO loops vs DO loops.  The macro language (%IF %DO etc) is used to generate SAS code.  It does not know about SAS datasets or the values of dataset variables.  It's just a text processing language.  The SAS data step language (IF DO etc) is used to read and process data.

When you write:

```
%if %str(first.Away_Team) %then count=1;
```

this is a macro %IF statement.  The macro language does not know about dataset variables such as first.Away_Team.  So the macro %if statement is testing whether the expression %str(first.Away_Team) is true or not.  This is just a text string to the macro language; it does not know that first.Away_Team is a data step variable that has a value of 1 or 0.  So it throws an error.

This should be just a regular IF statement:

```
if first.Away_Team then count=1
```

The data step IF statement can test the value of first.Away_Team.

Similar for your %DO loop at the end. You cannot: `%do i=count %to dim(x);` because the macro language %DO statement does not know that COUNT is a dataset variable with a value, or that dim(x) is the number of elements in an array named x.  To the macro language, they are both text strings.  You can `do i=count to dim(x);`

I would suggest you start by writing your data step with no macros or macro variables at all, and get that working like you want it, for FTHG and FTHGC.  Then after you know what the working SAS code is, you can try write a macro that will generate that code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Quentin!

I've changed my approach and got the code running!